# After save model data in view empty

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

after save model in view, the data in view are empty. For example if I add an comment to post and after saving the post my view is empty, no data will display. Why? How I solve the problem?

```
 var post = this.get('model');
 var comment = this.store.pushObject('comment');
 comment.set('text', ' thats some text');
 comment.set('created', '11111212');
 comment.save().then(function(resolvedComment){
   post.get('comments').addObject(resolvedComment);
   post.save();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the [transition guide](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md) you should change your code to this:

```
var post = this.get('model');
var comment = this.store.createRecord('comment');
comment.set('text', ' thats some text');
comment.set('created', '11111212');
comment.save().then(function(resolvedComment){
  post.get('comments').pushObject(resolvedComment);
  post.save();
});
```

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes I am update from 0.13 to 1.0 but, after saveing the view is empty :( I don't know why :(

Comment: @user1099381, can you show some more code of what's going on in your app? It will be easier to find the problem I guess

Answer (score 0):

OK here you get my controller, the method would fire if you click on save-button.

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    newComment: null,

    actions:{

        createIncidentComment: function(){
            var post = this.get('model');
            var state = post.get('postState');
            var newComment = this.get('newComment');
            var date = Date.now();
            var currentUser = this.get('controllers.application.user');
            var contr = this;
            if(newComment!= null){
                var comment = this.store.createRecord('comment',{
                    comment: newComment,
                    created: date,
                    context: postState,
                    reporter: currentUser
                });
                comment.save().then(function(){
                    post.get('comments').pushObject(comment);
                    post.save();
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :)

after save the post, I actually reload the model. In my example the model is the post.

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    newComment: null,

    actions:{

        createIncidentComment: function(){
            var post = this.get('model');
            var state = post.get('postState');
            var newComment = this.get('newComment');
            var date = Date.now();
            var currentUser = this.get('controllers.application.user');
            var contr = this;
            if(newComment!= null){
                var comment = this.store.createRecord('comment',{
                    comment: newComment,
                    created: date,
                    context: postState,
                    reporter: currentUser
                });
                comment.save().then(function(){
                    post.get('comments').pushObject(comment);
                    post.save().then(function(){
                       post.reload();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```